# Automatic Cell Height Without Custom Cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8

I would like the Subtitle-style cells in my iOS 8 table view to resize automatically in height to allow subtitle content of any number of lines.  And, I would like to accomplish this without using custom cells, if possible.  That is, I would like to use the "canned" prototype cells that are available when dragging a new TableViewController to the story board.

I have found that this is easy to do with Basic-style cells:  that is, prototype cells with Style set to "Basic" so that there is just one label in the cell -- "Title", by default.  This is the label that is accessible by cell.textLabel!.text in code.  If I set that textLabel's number of lines to 0, and add the two lines below to viewDidLoad(), then the cell heights resize automatically:

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 144.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

All without having to define a custom cell or muck around with auto-layout or constraints.  (In fact, I find it's not possible to add constraints to a canned prototype cell.)

But if I change the cell Style to "Subtitle," so that there are two labels in the cell -- textLabel and detailTextLabel in code -- then the cells do not automatically resize in height, even after setting both (or either) line numbers to 0 and playing around with different estimatedRowHeight values.

Am I missing something, or is it not possible to automatically resize cell height without a custom cell?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or is it not possible to automatically resize cell height without a custom cell?

Yes, it is not possible. And the reason is the reason that you gave. The automatic-resizing-cell-height feature *depends* upon *internal constraints*. But, as you have rightly said:

> it's not possible to add constraints to a canned prototype cell.

However, note that you can accomplish what you want without supplying a cell subclass (though personally I like supplying one). You can just design your cell, constraints and all, right there in the prototype cell — the Custom prototype cell.